# Use function to add to div

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function below and I need to append its result inside a div called test. How can i do it?

```
function(response) {
    alert('Your name is ' + response[0].name);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have something like:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

in your HTML.

Also, I'm guessing that you wish to append the value of `response[0].name` because your function has no return statement.

In which case:

```
var testdiv = document.getElementById("test");
testdiv.innerHTML += response[0].name;
```

Comment: This worked like a charm :)
Everyone was correct somehow :)
Thanks everyone, thanks :)

Comment: Hey , sorry for bothering you again...
I modified my function, i have this function right now, am i doing something wrong here?

FB.api(
  {
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = me()
OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())'
  },
  function(response) {
for(i=0;i<response.data.length;i++) {
var testdiv = document.getElementById("test");
testdiv.innerHTML += response[i].name;
}

}

Answer (score 1):

In order to append the data, not just write over what's there, you'll need to use this

```
function(response) {
    //Get current HTML in div
    current = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
    //Add your code to the current HTML.  You may want a <br /> in there.
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = current + 'Your name is ' + response[0].name;
}
```

Of course, this could be summarized as:

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += 'Your name is ' + response[0].name;
```